# Excel, при открытии больших html-таблиц тег colspan игнорируется

Tags: excel, export

Есть большие таблицы (~300 000 строк), описанные как HTML-документ. Начало документа интерпретируется правильно, но в какой-то момент столбцы начинают двигаться, то есть тег **colspan** просто игнорируется.

Таблицы описанные примерно так:

```
    <html>
    <table border="2" rules="all">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
       <col width="50">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
        <th colspan="3" >col 3</th>
        <th>col 4</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td colspan="3">3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td colspan="3">7</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td colspan="3">11</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>14</td>
            <td colspan="3">15</td>
            <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td colspan="3">19</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr></tbody>
    </table>
    </html>
```

Но получается как то так...

```
_____________________________________________
| col 1 | col 2 |       col 3       | col 4 |
---------------------------------------------
| 1     | 2     | 3                 |       |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
... ~20 000 - 250 000
| 1     | 2     | 3     |     |     | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3     |     |     | 4     |
---------------------------------------------
```

А должно быть так

```
_____________________________________________
| col 1 | col 2 |       col 3       | col 4 |
---------------------------------------------
| 1     | 2     | 3                 |       |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
... ~20 000 - 250 000
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
| 1     | 2     | 3                 | 4     |
---------------------------------------------
```

Я конвертирую HTML в Excel (xlsx\xlsb) с помощью VBS, но тот же эффект будет, если вы просто откроете документ в Excel и позволите ему распознаться. Использую Excel 2019.

Для примера добавлю скрипт на VBS, стабильно ломается на 32766 строке...

```
    dim objFSO, objFile, CNT
    
    CNT = 100000
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\raw.html", True)
    
    objFile.WriteLine("<html><table border=2 rules='all'><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><col width=50><thead><tr><th>col 1</th><th>col 2</th><th colspan=3 >col 3</th><th>col 4</th></tr></thead><tbody>")
    
    For i = 1 To CNT
        objFile.WriteLine("<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td colspan=3>3</td><td>4</td></tr>")
    Next
    
    objFile.WriteLine("</tbody></table></html>")
    objFile.Close
    
    WScript.StdOut.Write "Raw file written: " & CNT & " lines. Star conversion..." & vbCrLf
    

    dim app, wbk
    dim indx
    
    Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbk = app.Workbooks.Open("c:\raw.html")
    app.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    wbk.SaveAs "c:\conv.xlsx", 51
    
    WScript.StdOut.Write "The file has been converted. Star checks..." & vbCrLf
    
    set sht1 = wbk.Sheets(1)
    
    indx = 1
    For Each cell In sht1.Range("C:C")
        
        If not cell.MergeCells Then
            WScript.StdOut.Write "Error in line " & indx & vbCrLf
            Exit For
        End If
        
        indx = indx + 1
        
        if indx > CNT Then
          WScript.StdOut.Write "Everything is fine" & vbCrLf
          Exit For
        End If
        
    Next
       
    wbk.Close False
    app.Quit
    
    set sht1 = Nothing
    set wbk = Nothing
    set app = Nothing
```

Нашел аналогичный вопрос у microsoft
https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/msoffice/forum/all/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-excel/7ef72a2b-7416-4bf7-ac91-4e86f10510d2

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77461415/22894332

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем? Почему это происходит или как обойти эту "фичу"?

Comment: Листы книг `.xls` содержали  2^15 (32768) строк. Похоже, ограничение тянется со времен Excel-2003

Comment: Как обойти, а то придется все глобально переделывать. Пора понял что ошибка возникает  в рамках одной таблицы <table>...</table>, то есть если в одном документе две таблицы подряд с размером до 32765 то еще не ломается.

Comment: А для чего вам объединённые ячейки вообще? Это зло :) Может быть, есть возможность отказаться от них?

Comment: Объединенные ячейки - вопрос дизайна, с таблицами работаю клиенты :)